# Who was Channah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, historical-figures, amoroim

Throughout the Gemara we find grandchildren of Channah. There's Rabbah bar bar Channah, and R Yitzchak bar bar Channah, both quoted extensively, and maybe others that I don't know about because I don't know all of Shas.

Who is Channah? There is an axiom, I don't know where to source it, that says that an Amora quoted by name in the Gemara was someone who could successfully daven to bring back the dead. So clearly if someone's name is in the Gemara they are a person of stature. So when the Gemara goes out of its way to *not* name Rabbah bar bar Channah's father, and to instead to name his grandmother (I'm assuming, from a name like Channah), I wonder why. I know we can just declare that "Channah could bring back people from the dead, and bar Channah couldn't" but I'm wondering if there's more out there in terms of specifics.

Is there a history associated with Channah that indicates her (or his) greatness, or why Rabbah and R' Yitzchok are named after Channah instead of their father?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I think the Ramchal says that every Amora could bring back the dead.

Comment: is it possible that their father's name was "Bar Channah"? Is there any instance where the talmud speaks of the character of "channah" as an independent ancestor and not a name following "Bar"?

Comment: Schottenstein on Moed Katan 16b bring the Rashash who explains that Chanah was male and a brother of Rabbi Chiya.

Comment: See also [Sanhedrin 5a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.5a.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi).